# Solve logical equivalence of $\neg (p \land \neg q)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How do I break down $\neg (p \land \neg q)$?

I know that $\neg (p \to q) \equiv p \land \neg q$, so I could say

$$
\neg (p \land \neg q) \equiv \neg (\neg (p \to q)) \equiv p \to q
$$

which is true for $\neg p$ or $q$, but is it clever to involve implication when I already have eliminated them?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking here. What do you mean break down? Are you trying to do conjunctive normal form or disjunctive normal form or something?

Comment: Since $p\to q$ is defined to mean $(\neg p)\lor q,$ we could ask how you know that $\neg (p\to q)\equiv (p\land \neg q),$ in other words, to prove that $\neg ((\neg p)\lor q)\equiv (p\land  \neg q).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may use
$$
\neg (a \land b)=\neg a \lor \neg b
$$ giving
$$
\neg (p \land \neg q)=\neg p \lor \neg (\neg q)=\neg p \lor q.
$$